# Python Lambda for Multiple Endpoints API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS api gateway with 2 endpoints:

- /items/
- /itemsBulk/

/items/ will retrieve a single record based on the input json (which contains the column name and value to do the lookup on the dynamodb backend)
/itemsBulk/ will retrieve records on the input date range (within the json request payload) and send back the records that fall within that.

I want a single python lambda to receive both requests and respond. How do I write the code for that?

For example, in this AWS [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-dynamo-db.html#http-api-dynamo-db-create-function) - the index.js file has the routes and what to do. I want to do the same in python.

Any insight appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: so, Python lambda handler has entrypoint defined as function `def lambda_handler(event, context)` as You see there is the event object which AWS provides. You can access the enpoint similar as in the JS example by accessing the event `routeKey` key like that `event['routeKey']` in python code, [HERE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.proxy-format) is the complete event schema

Comment: The above comment gives a pretty simple and usable approach, but I would like to add one thing here is that it would be a hardcoded check for the endpoint routekey and if more endpoints are added then it would be needed to be added everytime

Comment: In Python you can try it with Flask by defining your own routes for more simplicity on the management of URI, routes and parameters, even if, as Take_Care_ mentionned, it's totally possible to manage it through the event JSON object. For example, you can get 'routeKey', and according the value returned, you will execute the wanted Python function to do some actions.